# Extracting 2D surfaces from point cloud

Tags: python-3.x, point-clouds, ransac, open3d

I have a large number of points representing several geological beds with many outliers. I have tried *Ransac*, *DBSCAN*, *GMM clustering* to differentiate between the point clusters representing different beds but they fail in complex scenarios e.g. when two beds are crossing. I have used Open3d, but there I can manually separate the points only.

Is there any way I can extract possible surfaces (representative of beds) from the point cloud automatically?

Any help in this direction will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You may look at instace segmentation for point cloud. It was interesting article about it https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.5721/EuJRS20154831